# Graph of $\log_2(2-x)$: what is wrong in my transformational approach?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

In the graph of $\log_2(2-x)$
can I have the transformational approach of
$\log_2 x$ >> $\log_2(-x)$ >> $\log_2(-x+2)$ or $\log_2(2-x)$ but after all this graph comes wrong but with differential approach graph comes right.
What is wrong in my graph transformational approach?

Comment: Try putting values such as -2, 0 and 1 in for x and plotting the points.  This should help you see which transformation to take first and which to take second.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform the transformation $\log_{2}(-x)>>\log_{2}(-x+2)$, you want to write $\log_{2}(-x+2)$ as $\log_{2}(-(x-2))$, since this shows that you are shifting the graph of $y=\log_{2}(-x)$ two units to the right.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more clear to do the shift before the reflection: $$\log_2(x)\to\log_2(x+2)\to\log_2(-x+2)$$
Speaking loosely, you enacted the horizontal shift with a ${}+2$ right on inside the function input parentheses. But a horizontal transformation should be enacted upon the input variable. And if you had already done the reflection, there is a layer of minus sign between the input variable and the function input parentheses.